# Trying to access items stored in a list in a class in Python but keep getting the object location

Tags: python, list, class

I have several classes that were built, one that includes a list of items, and I have to access the list from a function call, using one of the other classes. The issue is, that when I try to access it, I keep getting the object, rather than the list of items in the class.

```py
class Owner:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pets = []


def get_pets_string(a_owner):
    result = "{0} {1}'s pets are: {2}.".format(a_owner.name.first, a_owner.name.last, a_owner.pets)
    return result
```

I get the owner names just fine, and I know the pet names are in the list, but cannot access them at all. I've tried using `a_owner.pets.name` in various ways, I've tried to access the main class, but I am not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
class Name():
    def __init__(self, first: str, last: str) -> None:
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

class Owner:
    def __init__(self, name: Name, pets: list) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.pets = pets

    def get_pets_names(self) -> list:
        pets_names = []
        for pet in self.pets:
            pets_names.append(pet.first)
        return pets_names

def get_pets_string(a_owner: Owner) -> str:
    result = "{0} {1}'s pets are: {2}.".format(a_owner.name.first, a_owner.name.last, a_owner.get_pets_names())
    return result

a_owner = Owner(Name("John", "Smith"), [Name("Cat", None), Name("Dog", None)])
print(get_pets_string(a_owner))
```

Answer (score 0):

`a_owner.pets` will give you the list.
You can pretty-print it in this way:

```
from pprint import pp

pp(a_owner.pets)
```

If there's anything in the list, so `len(a_owner.pets) > 0`, then
`a_owner.pets[0]` will give you the 1st element.

To conveniently format all list elements into a single string
you can use this `.join()` expression:

```
print(', '.join(a_owner.pets))
```

Comment: Thank you, qq- when I try to access a_owner.pets, I don't get the list, I get the object address in python- something that looks like this-> <__main__.Pet object at 0x7fe7339ad128>. It's strange because I would expect to get the list, and because of that, I cannot do any sort of list manipulation to it. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Well, that's not the behavior of the code you posted. Apparently some piece of code assigned `self.pets = some_pet` when it meant to `self.pets.append(some_pet)`. Python is dynamic; it lets you assign e.g. `x = 'one'` followed by `x = 1`, which changes the object type. If you start out with `list` type, it is usually a mistake to change it to another type such as `Pet`.